# Finding the limiting distribution of $\frac{X_n -n}{\sqrt{2n}}$

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Let $X_n \sim \chi^2 (n)$ for all $n$. I would like to show when $n\to\infty$

$$\frac{X_n -n}{\sqrt{2n}}\to N(0,1)$$

where $N(0,1)$ is normal distribution. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\left(Z_i\right)_i$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variable following standard normal distribution, such that $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^nZ_i^2$, then

$\frac{X_n-n}{\sqrt{2n}} = \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i^2\right)-n}{\sqrt{2n}} = \frac{n^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i^2\right)-1}{\sqrt{2/n}} = \sqrt{n}\left[\frac{n^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i^2\right)-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right]$.

Since $n^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i^2\right)$ can be viewed as the sample mean of $Z_i^2$, which follows a $\chi^2(1)$, it follows that

$\frac{X_n-n}{\sqrt{2n}} =\sqrt{n}\left[\frac{n^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i^2\right)-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right] \overset{d}\to N(0,1)$.

Comment: Please avoid just giving complete solutions to obvious homework-style questions. See our [help/on-topic] in relation to *homework*, which calls for guidance and hints. More direct answers for problems with serious attempts are fine but to all appearances this was just a flat out request for you to do their work for them. Actually giving complete answers deprives people of the opportunity to learn to do these for themselves -- which is the entire point of setting such exercises in the first place! (Any substantive benefit  only comes by actually working at it, not by posting it here)